# Multiple Keycloak instances versus one instance with many realms?

Tags: single-sign-on

I plan to use Keycloak to authenticate / authorize various users and services across the organization.

These include:

- Service-to-service
- End-users connecting from public internet
- Intranet users accessing internal services

I see two ways of doing this:

1. A single internet-facing Keycloak instance with realms for each user type
2. Many Keycloak instances (for example and end-user instance, intranet instance, etc.) with one or a few realms each

What are the security and deployment trade-offs of each approach?

Comment: If someone could create the tag `keycloak` that would be excellent